# How to make an ArrayList of Classes?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, java-8, factory

How can I add a bunch of classes to an `ArrayList<MyBaseClass>` and then later retrieve a Class (derived from, but not `MyBaseClass`) from the `ArrayList` and use it to generate a new object of the actual Class retrieved (i.e. not `MyBaseClass` since that is abstract)

All classes that need to be added all derive from the same *abstract* base Class (`MyBaseClass`)

I can't really think of another way to achieve what I want to do, so hopefully this is possible... ?

Comment: Why not just do exactly that?

Comment: Yes. It works..Goahead.

Comment: how do I do add it? just use .class ? I am not new to Java but haven't programmed in years so I'm rusty, how would I instantiate the object from the class retrieved?

Comment: `clazz.newInstance()`?

Comment: ah ok, I'll try that - thanks

Comment: You want a list of classes? `ArrayList<Class<? extends MyBaseClass>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent the use of reflection, you are probably looking for the [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Here is a simple example how to implement it using Java 8:

```
private void run() {
    List<Supplier<MyBaseClass>> factories = Arrays
            .asList(Impl1::new, Impl2::new, Impl3::new);
    List<MyBaseClass> baseClassInstances = factories.stream()
            .map(Supplier::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass {
}

public class Impl1 extends MyBaseClass {
}

public class Impl2 extends MyBaseClass {
}

public class Impl3 extends MyBaseClass {
}
```

See also [How should I select which concrete implementation should be instantiated based on the user choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272566/how-should-i-select-which-concrete-implementation-should-be-instantiated-based-o)

Comment: Of course, it only makes sense if `factories` is used more than once. Otherwise it’s an unnecessary complication of `List<MyBaseClass> baseClassInstances = Arrays.asList(new Impl1(), new Impl2(), new Impl3());`

Comment: You are right, but that is exactly what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I think you're asking for:

```
// get a list from somewhere
List<MyBaseClass> list = new ArrayList<MyBaseClass>();

// call list.add(...) a few times

// iterate over all the objects and check their sub class with "instanceof"
for (MyBaseClass item : list) {
    if (item instanceof MySubClass) {
        MySubClass subItem = (MySubClass) item;
        item.doThing();
    } else if (item instanceof OtherSubClass) {
        OtherSubClass subItem = (OtherSubClass) item;
        item.doThing();
    }
}
```

But if you find yourself needing to check if an object is the instance of a particular class, you're probably doing something wrong.  Try creating an abstract method in `MyBaseClass` that can be implemented by each sub class in its own special way.  Then, you can simplify the `for` loop to just this:

```
for (MyBaseClass item : list) {
    item.doThing();
}
```